# Watermark on selected pages

Tags: watermark

I would like to have the watermark from Page 3 all the way to the end. I am currently using

```
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\newwatermark[allpages,color=red!10,angle=45,scale=4.5,xpos=0,ypos=0]{DRAFT}
```

which generate the DRAFT on all pages.

Comment: @Kurt Thanks Kurt, I followed your instructions and used: \newwatermark[pages=3-,color=red!10,angle=45,scale=4.5,xpos=0,ypos=0]{DRAFT} which worked perfectly! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

In the manual of `xwatermark` you can read in note Note 3.1, page 6 (you get it with `texdoc xwatermark` from the console)  which possibilities you have to give the pages which should be printed with watermark.

For example you can use the option `pages=4-15` to get a watermark on all the pages 4 until 15.