# Watermark from second page

Tags: watermark

How do I add watermark into document, but from second page. Or better, from, instance, from second page and to, for instance, 10th page of document?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Watermark on selected pages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213285/watermark-on-selected-pages)

Comment: @Null, superb, but how do I set watermark from 2nd page to LAST page, i.e., how do I get number of pages inside latex doc?

Comment: Are you using the xwatermark package or would you be willing to use another one?

Comment: @Null Unless the OP confirms that he is using `xwatermark` this could be not a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, I am not using `xwatermark`, but `\usepackage{draftwatermark}`, so I use `draftwatermark`.

Comment: Closing voters: this is *not* a duplicate of the linked question; there the problem is specific to `xwatermark` which is not used by the OP here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one option using the [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package; read the package documentation to see all the customization possibilities it offers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[contents={}]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AddEverypageHook{
  \ifnum\value{page}=1\relax
  \else
  \backgroundsetup{contents={my text}}
  \fi
\BgMaterial
}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

Use the

```
\backgroundsetup{}
```

command in the `\else` branch to place the desired material, at the desired location, with the specified attributes.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Gonzalo's answer, just using [`draftwatermark`](http://ctan.org/pkg/draftwatermark):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{draftwatermark,xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\SetWatermarkAngle{45}
\SetWatermarkColor{red!30}
\SetWatermarkScale{5}
\SetWatermarkText{%
  \ifnum\value{page}=1\relax% Nothing on page 1;
  \else DRAFT \fi}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

For conditional printing of content, make sure you specify this condition as part of `\SetWatermarkText`.